# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<MyData>', flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dynamic, casting

In the flutter widget, I am storing the list of objects of type `MyData` in memory with the Hive package.

But when Hive returns the data, it returns it in the `List<dynamic>` and I want to convert it to `List<MyData>` but I am getting the following error in doing so

```
E/flutter (22594): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<MyData>'
```

code:

```
List<MyData> data = (monthBox.get(DateTime.now().day).toList() as List<MyData>);
```

can we cast `List<dynamic>` to `List<MyData>` without iterating on it?